# Finding variable patterns using C++ STL Library

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, stl

I have a file in which I have to look for a pattern.

The pattern is like this:

```
"ABCD"
```

A, B, C, D are variables which can be 0-9 and A-F, and nothing else.

Few sample string in this file is :

```
at+creg=2 
OK 

at+creg? 
+CREG: 2,1,"03EB","3AC7" 
+CREG: 2,1,"03FC","9AC9"
```

My pattern matching code should output:

> 03EB, 3AC7, 03FC, 9AC9

I want to do this using a functions from STL library.

If we have two strings, such as:

```
std::string str ("There are two needles in this haystack with needles.");
std::string str2 ("needle");
```

then we can use

```
str.find(str2);
```

to look for the pattern *needle*.

But in my case I do not have a fixed string, as A,B,C,D above are variable. So kindly help me to understand how to proceed here.

Comment: So you want to find four-digit hexadecimal numbers in a file? You could probably use the C++11 [regular expression functionality](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) for this.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes I want to search for those hex. Can you give an example in the current context, since I have never used regex earlier. Please post this as an answer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Do I need to search for "****" pattern?

Comment: The pattern in your case would be something like `"[0-9A-F]{4}"`. [Search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) for that pattern in all [lines you read](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: You need a regex in order to do this. If you use C++11 you can use the regex header, and if not you can use `boost::regex`.

Comment: Regular expressions do seem like exactly the tool that's appropriate for this. Unfortunately, there is no regular expression api in the STL. But there is a regular expression api in c++ standard library. Maybe you can use that as well?

Comment: @user2079303: "STL"  is an outdated term, and when used by novices it often means "the parts of the C++ library not inherited from C".

Comment: @MSalters : Really? What's the appropriate term then?

Comment: @AimanAl-Eryani: The _Standard Library_ is the new overall term. You can't really tell the STL components apart anymore, nor is there a good reason to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are searching hexadecimal digits. If the case of letters is not important then you can apply standard C function `std::isxdigit` declared in header `<cctype>`. Usually C standard functions are placed in the global namespace. So you may use ::isxdigit to distinguish it from the C++ function with the same name that has two parameters. Otherwise you can wrap the function in std::function or cast the function to required type.

Here is a demonstrative program. Instead of `std::find_if` algorithm I used `std::copy_if` algorithm just for the demonstrative purpose.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream is( " ABC 123AA43 Jh12 76-12 fedcba1" );

    std::copy_if ( std::istream_iterator<std::string>( is ),
                   std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
                   std::ostream_iterator<std::string>( std::cout, "\n" ),
                   []( const std::string &s )
                   {
                       return std::all_of( std::begin( s ), std::end( s ), ::isxdigit );
                   } );

}
```

The output is

```
ABC
123AA43
fedcba1
```

Comment: `std::isxdigit`  or `::isxdigit` ? Tiny inconsistency in your answer there.

Comment: @MSalters I used ::isxdigit because as a rule C standard functions are placed in the global namespace Though it is not necessary. I used global namesapce to avoid an ambiguity with the C++ function with the same name. Otherwise the function can be wrapped in std::function.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions do what you want. Here is an example on how they work:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  // regular expressions which has the format you desire to match later
  regex isHexadecimal(R"(([[:d:]]|A|B|C|D|E|F)+)");
  string text = "asdlkfj 1C3AF";
  smatch result;

  regex_search (text, result, isHexadecimal);

  for (int i=0; i < result.size(); i++) {
      //result.position(i); // here are your positions
  }
  return 1;
}
```

All the magic happens in this line: `regex isHexadecimal(R"(([[:d:]]|A|B|C|D|E|F)+)");`
The `R"(textstringtext)"` syntax is for raw strings (strings in which you can have special characters without having to escape them).
The regex itself is `([[:d:]]|A|B|C|D|E|F)+`:
`[[:d:]]` is for digit.
`|` means or.
`A`, `B` are single characters to be matched.
`+` means "one or more of".

Thus, the expression will catch a sequence with one or more digit(from 0 to 9) or A or B or C or D or E or F.

Comment: I get error on this line regex isHexadecimal(R"(([[:d:]]|A|B|C|D|E|F)+)");  it says 'R' : undeclared identifire and also Syntax error ')'

Comment: What compiler are you using? Note that using a raw string is not necessary, but it's highly probably that if your compiler doesn't support them, it would not support the standard C++11 <regex> library either.

Comment: I am using msvs 2010 and made a win32 console application

Comment: msvs 2010 can barely be said to support C++11 =(. You will have to either: upgrade to 2012 or above, get the boost library and use the `boost` namespace in place of `std` or resort to Vlad's solution.